# Getting selected options with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html-select, selectors-api

I wonder if it's possible in Javascript to get the currently selected options in a `<select multiple>` field using the Selctors API rather than a "stupid" iteration over all options.

`select.querySelectorAll('option[selected="selected"]')` only returns the options that were marked as preselected in the original HTML, which is not what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: I think your only option is to iterate over all `option` elements and filter out the ones that are not selected.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll('option:checked')`

Works even on IE9 ;)

Comment: [Should work with 9.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:checked), Browser compatibility at the bottom

Comment: If jQuery is an option then you could use the `:selected` Selector

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The tramp here is that works with "checked" and not "selected"

Answer (score 0):

As described in

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

you can get the currently selected index with
selectObject.selectedIndex

It also changes in a `change` eventListener.

For example:

```
id_selected = document.querySelector('#sel').selectedIndex;
console.log(document.querySelector('#sel')[id_selected]);
```

Comment: I think that last line may need to be `console.log(document.querySelector('#sel').options[id_selected]);`

Answer (score -1):

I was also experienced your issue, I have a feeling it's to do with JavaScript not recognising changes in the DOM.

Here is a solution:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/HQqBN/1/)

```
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function () {
    var select = document.getElementById('select');
    var options = getSelectedOptions(select);
    console.log(options);
};

function getSelectedOptions(select) {
    var result = [];
    var options = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected)
            result.push(options[i]);
    };
    return result;
}
```

Comment: JS recognizes these changes to the DOM. The problem is that the `selected` DOM property is non-serializable. The `selected` attribute corresponds to the `defaultSelected` DOM property, so querying for the attribute as in `[selected]` will return elements that have `defaultSelected` DOM property set to `true`.